# I can't overwrite clean theme CSS in Moodle

Tags: css, moodle

I have problem with overwriting style css from Clean theme.

I tried in dashboard admin panel to write my own css and not working, I can't overwrite.

Also I wrote !Important in css and cleared cache in admin panel and not working (Also cleared cache in browser and still same problem can't overwrite default css style).

Also I tried with only wrote only exactly targeted class and all path but wihout sucess.

Can anyone help me, please, thank you in advance!
Best regards!

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS for us to check? It could be a specificity issue, a naming issue, an issue with the DOM, or something else.

Comment: This is Moodle clean theme ( https://moodle.org/ ), there is no my own HTML, I'm rewriting default .css

Answer (score 0):

your colour value is invalid
you typed " #ff000 "
try " #ff0000 "

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Change theme and works fine